# CSS differences between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues getting one particular element to look the same in Firefox and Chrome.

This screenshot is how it looks in Firefox (and how it should look - a box, with a date inside).

[image: Firefox - correct example]

This screenshot is how it looks in Chrome.

[image: Chrome - incorrect example]

I've been playing with Firebug to try and fix it, but whatever I do, I cannot get the background to work in the same way as it does on Firefox. Anyone able to help with this?

The page is at http://zachlockwood.com/wp - thanks.

HTML/CSS for the element in question:

```
.bit-events-narrow .bit-date .bit-event-data { text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 16px !important; background: #552412 !important; color: #f0f0e6 !important; line-height: 18px !important; padding-top: 8px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important; padding-left: 3px !important; padding-right: 3px !important; font-family: 'Conv_Haymaker' !important; height: 40px !important; width: 40px !important; } 

.bit-date { text-align: center !important;  line-height: 20px !important; }  

.bit-date a { width: 50px !important; background: #552412 !important; }
```

---

```
<td class="bit-date">
<a class="bit-event-data" href="http://www.bandsintown.com/event/7082285?app_id=wpjs_zachlockwood.com&artist=Zach+Lockwood&came_from=39" target="_blank" data-bit-event-id="7082285" style="font-family: 'Conv_Haymaker'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; color: rgb(240, 240, 230); text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; line-height: 18px; text-align: center; vertical-align: baseline; direction: ltr; background-color: rgb(85, 36, 18); background-image: none; background-repeat: repeat; background-position: 0% 0%; background-attachment: scroll; opacity: 1; width: 40px; height: 40px; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 8px 3px 5px; border-width: 0px; border-color: rgb(240, 240, 230); border-style: none; position: static; display: inline; visibility: visible; z-index: auto; overflow: visible; white-space: normal; clip: auto; clear: none; cursor: pointer; list-style: disc outside none; marker-offset: auto;">Nov 16</a>
</td>
```

**note that the HTML is generated by the BandsInTown plugin, and this was not added by me.

Comment: Can you show the HTML and CSS for that element here please? Check out [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Comment: its a bloody nightmare of inline styles (its a wordpress site), you don't want to see it. my guess is its because of `-webkit-margin-before-collapse` and `-webkit-margin-after-collapse` being set to `collapse`. looking at dev tools / firebug, there are a LOT of additional webkit-only styles that are applied in comparison to Firefox.

Comment: add display:block in the anchor tag.

Comment: I've added the HTML/CSS to the question. As it uses the BandsInTown plugin there are unfortunately a lot of inline styles added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your `a` tag should be `block`

Try this:

```
.bit-date a { display: block!important; }
```

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! Will mark this as the answer as soon as StackOverflow's time limit lets me.